# Where is boost::asio::windows::stream_handle in boost 1.46.1?

Tags: c++, boost, pipe, boost-asio

Once uppon a time we had boost code like:

```
typedef BoostAsioPipe pipe;
#elif defined(BOOST_POSIX_API)
typedef boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor pipe;
#elif defined(BOOST_WINDOWS_API)
typedef boost::asio::windows::stream_handle pipe;
#else
#   error "Unsupported platform."
#endif
```

but now, for example on windows compiler tralls us that stream_handle  is not a part of boost::asio... so where is it now? (and is stream_descriptor  in the same place or it also moved)?

*Update*

Stupid me: there is something like `boost::asio::windows::pipe` now but compiler gives `C3083`

```
#elif defined(BOOST_WINDOWS_API)
    typedef boost::asio::windows::pipe  pipe;
#else
```

Comment: Are you sure it disapeared ? According to the doc, it's still there : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/asio/windows/stream_handle.hpp

Comment: Its still part of boost, maybe some headers changed, so you now have to explicitly include <boost/asio/windows/stream_handle.hpp> to make use of it. I don't see the include in your code example at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? (from http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.4.8/doc/asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html)

Windows random-access HANDLEs are only available at compile time when targeting Windows and only when the I/O completion port backend is used (which is the default). A program may test for the macro BOOST_ASIO_HAS_WINDOWS_STREAM_HANDLE to determine whether they are supported.
(also valid for BOOST_ASIO_HAS_WINDOWS_RANDOM_ACCESS_HANDLE)